# Ubuntu GTX 1660 corrupted graphics

Tags: boot, nvidia

When I use a live usb for ubuntu 18.04 LTS (or others debian distros actually), depending on what options I choose in grub, I get stuck on  either a screen tearing, looking like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNhV6.jpg

or stuck on a message saying:

```
BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

Just the default "live mode" results in a screen tearing like the screenshot ^

I have a GTX 1660 
System Model ROG Strix GL10CS_GL10CS
I disabled secure boot in the bios also

I tried various usb drives or iso. still the same..

What else could I try to fix this ?

Comment: Have you updated your BIOs/firmware to the latest version offered by the vendor?  Also try the latest available kernel, also use 18.04.4 (or 5) not 18.04.1 if you want the 18.04 release.  The "nomodeset" word on the kernel line is necessary until you install the proprietary Nvidia drivers.

Comment: It seems that using "nomodset" does not help, at least in my case. It leads to a black screen (no corrupted like the screeshot I added before). With nomodeset, I first see the "booting logs" (text diaplyed while it boots) but then I get the black screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it:

First booted in the Ubutnu installation (the one with corrupted graphics) but I tapped on the SHIFT key as it booted to enter grub menu

then I chose advanced options and booted using recovery option

I pressed ALT-F4 (maybe F3... ) while booting and chose the option root

Now I was in command line root and connected to wifi using the following:

```
service network-manager restart
```

then:

`nmcli device wifi rescan` ( this was optional for me)

then list networks:

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

and to connect:

```
nmcli device wifi connect SSID password 123455
```

(I replaced SSID with my network name)

and finally

```
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

rebooted and problem solved